# How to install these project in jenkins so that option can be given in one project only

Tags: maven, jenkins

Project TestMV

I have project TestMV which has dependency of project TestMV1.

I have deployed these projects in jenkins separately and pass the parameter in Goals and option section  like install -Dversion=13.2.00 and this is done in project TestMV1 configuration as well.what I want to configure this install -

Dversion=13.2.00 in project TestMV only and this should be shared in project

TestMV1 in jenkins job also. and more this should be work in eclipse also.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.TestMV</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestMV</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>TestMV</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version>13.2.00</version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.TestMV1</groupId>
      <artifactId>TestMV1</artifactId>
      <version>${version}</version>
       </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Project TestMV1

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.TestMV1</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestMV1</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>TestMV1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <version>13.2.00</version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When passing the install -dversion in goal section of project TestMV configuration.

How can we can pass to -dversion to project b in jenkins rather writing the install -dversion in goal section of the project TestMV1 configuration in jenkins.

project TestMV  has dependency of TestMV1

Comment: This question is not clear to me. Could you please describe in more detail what you want to achieve? Please edit the question to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the global variable in jenking and has passed this in the goal and option section like install -Dversion=${version}. done in the both maven project.

problem resolved.
thanks

Comment: This way is not working while send this parameter from eclipse command line to POM where I am getting this like ${version}